# How can I change security group on EC2 via API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I created a security group by using java SDK. Now, I want to add this security group to one of my EC2 instances. Is it possible via API???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security Groups are associated with Elastic Network Interfaces (ENI), and ENIs are associated with instances:

```
Instance -> ENI(s) -> Security Group(s)
```

Therefore, you would use:

```
ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttributeRequest request = 
     new ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttributeRequest()
       .withGroups("sg-903004f8", "sg-1a2b3c4d")
       .withNetworkInterfaceId("eni-686ea200");
```

Use the ENI that is currently attached to the EC2 instance.

See: [Java `modifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#modifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttributeRequest-)